# how does returning a char vs int variables works in C?

Tags: c, char, int, return

How does returning a local variable that is int works but char doesn't ?
Code snippet

```
int myfn1() {
int i=10;
return i;
}

char myfn2() {
char buf[10]="Hello";
return buf;
}

int main(){
printf("%d\n", myfn1());
printf("%s\n", myfn2());
}
```

Output:

```
10
Segmentation fault
```

I am new to C programming and I know that local variable's scope is within that function and myfn2 crashing makes sense for me but how does myfn1 works ?

Comment: `buf` appears to be neither a local variable nor a `char`. Are there maybe a few bits missing?

Comment: You aren't returning a char. `buf` isn't a `char`.

Comment: I think you should stop and study a bit more about pointers and their relationship with strings/arrays (note I did not say chars).

Comment: `myFn1` is returning the *value* of `i`. So it works. (`i` is being returned in a return register in the underlying assembly.) Your `myfn2` has a `char []` for `buf` (**not** a `char`!), and `return buf` returns the *address* of `buf` which is *temporary* (on the stack of `myfn2`). So after `myfn2` returns, the address for `buf` is not longer valid. This would be true even if `myfn2` return value were declared correctly.

Comment: Pay attention to compiler errors/warnings, it should have pointed out a problem wiht `myfn2`. (If not, turn up the error level).

Comment: @night_hawk Are you trying to return the whole array in `myfn2()`?

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code

```
char myfn2() {
buf[10]="Hello";
return buf;
}
```

is a summary of what should not be done !

`char myfn2()` promises to return a `char` and you are returning a `char *`.
`return buf[0];` or `return *buf;` would get rid of the error and would be correct since you would return a integral value - but you display a `char` with `%c` and not `%s`, the latter being for a null terminated char array.

But beware :

```
char * myfn2() {
buf[10]="Hello";
return buf;
}
```

Would normally not cause an error, but would be plain undefined behaviour since function would return the **address** of an automatic variable that could be destroyed before you can use it.

I think you still have to learn C ...

Answer (score 0):

In C, the name of an array is a `pointer` to its first element so you are returning a `pointer` to a `char` instead of a `char`, which is what you declared `myfn2()` returns.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is *not* returning of returning a `char *`.  That is perfectly fine.

The problem is de-referencing that pointer to a location that is no longer valid.  `printf("%d\n", myfn1());` printf the *value* is the `int`.  Printing the *value* of the pointer, like-wise, is OK:

```
int main(void) {
  printf("%p\n", (void*) myfn2());  // OK - pointer's value is printed
  printf("%s\n", myfn2());          // Bad - code attempts sting access to invalid pointer.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

printf("%s\n", myfn2());

%s ==> starts reading from the address and ends when it reaches to '/0', but you are passing a char which is having some 8 bit data, max value it can hold is 255.

that input char value will be considered as address and that address range is very small (generally 32 bit/64 bit address), so it will not find any physical memory for the input. so we are getting segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

how does myfn1 works?

It works because you are returning the value stored in the variable 'i' and not the address of 'i'.

myfn2 returns the address of array 'buf' which is no longer valid.